# Removing padding from layerlist item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to add a bitmap as a Splash Screen.
I have created a separate Splash Theme and added android:windowBackground to a Layer list drawable containing that bitmap.

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bg</item>
    </style>
```

Following is the code for my layer list drawable(@drawable/splash_bg):

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Currently the drawable looks like this:

[image: splash sample]

I want to remove the extra padding around the image, without streching the image. Some thing like Center Crop in ImageView.

If the center crop is not possible, then i would like to make it fit horizontally(without stretching), and show a solid background at the top and bottom.

So far I have tried all the attributes of gravity, and tried using the inset tag, but all of them seem to be stretching the image.

Answer (score 0):

`windowBackground` isn't best way to set up such image (splash), it probably should be used only with `color` (if with `bitmap` then with `tileMode="repeat"` in some cases). there is no reliable way to set up different bitmaps for different screen resolutions/ratios. it would be the best to set `ImageView` with proper `scaleType`, `CENTER_CROP` seems to be the best option

Comment: But image view can only be used in a layout(not in a drawable). And I want to show this bitmap as splash before the MainActivity's setContentView method is called.

Comment: proper way would be to create another splash-only `Activity` with `ImageView`, when some configuration job is done, then pass to `MainActivity`. in fact you don't have much choice, eventaully you can `setContentView` with some splash layout and when everything is loaded then `setContentView` again with content layout, but this isn't recomended way... `setContentView` may be heavy operation and it's the best to call it at the beggining of `Activity` lifecycle, not during runtime